# Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram, $M$ is a fixed point on $AB$. Erect $N$ on $CD$ satisfying the area which is limited by $MC,MD,NA,NB$ is maximum.

Tags: geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a parallelogram, $M$ is a fixed point on $AB$. Erect $N$ on $CD$ satisfying the area  which is limited by $MC,MD,NA,NB$ is maximum.

---

Please help me in the way to approach this problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: Adding a diagram may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Put all the thing into Cartesian coordinates, with $A:=(0,0)$, now let $\overrightarrow{AD},\,\overrightarrow{AB}$ be the basis vectors.
Let $x=\frac{AM}{AB},\,y=\frac{ND}{CD}$.
It [can be shown](https://tio.run/##VZA/b8MgEMV3fwpGg3FjZ4QydOlWqVJGhCIwqWrFUCf@I6jlz@6e7ahVF@7e46d7unO6/7w43deVXhbNxFTQYuYGGhPWzkJnA7Vx5knFhMksTxwTgRjumYikytIyj5iArcEA0WOis554boHriF2BDhPHE7MDAyY@G2BABcBI3AqMmFQ86QomTl/NeJGT9kJYRw2Uys106mlHBzrOCnLuFy3DmcazYuLFdDJIWSpFopRHpfK4q7ApwFsmtEeHJ9QV2w9PbrDHf@f9Xvtevg5Nc6pd29QfUW4pbe7pLfcqeygHysHUJCXoygRK0zU/zUuUoYBJUFD/HDhLVBgfdue4Mrub7vU3@E2H2tXfsPaVogI9CwDhKR8ibmKmaIqzUojgZfkB) that $$\frac{\operatorname{Area}(PNQM)}{\operatorname{Area}(ABCD)}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{x(1-x)+y(1-y)}
{(2-x-y)(x+y)}\tag{1}$$
Then we maximize (1) wrt $y$ [getting](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x*%281-x%29%2By*%281-y%29%29%2F%28%282-x-y%29*%28x%2By%29%29%29%27%3D0+%26%26+0%3Cx%3C1+%26%26+0%3Cy%3C1) $$y=x.$$
Maybe that would help someone to bring purely geometrical solution.

Answer: $DN=AM$.

Comment: @Angelo I think it does not, because then the area is fixed and not maximized in general. Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion the verb “Erect” suggests an orthogonal projection.

Comment: In my opinion “Erect $N$ on $CD$” means to project $M$ orthogonally onto $CD$ in order to get $N$ and then obtain which is the point $M$ such that the area of $PNQM$ is biggest.

Comment: I solve the exercise in that way and I have got that the biggest area is obtained if $AM=\frac{1}{2}AH$ where $H$ is the orthogonal projection of $C$ on the line $AB$.